# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 11 row(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq

Tengo un método en linq que actualiza un valor de una tabla pero cuando llega ala linea SaveChangesAsync me manda el error:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 11 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Este es mi código:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> Put(short idAgenOriginal, short idAgen, string tipo, [FromBody] MyModel2 model)
        {
            try
            {               
                var model_campo = _context.MyModel.Where(x => x.Codigo == model.Codigo && x.Otro == model.Otro).SingleOrDefault();

                if (model_campo != null)
                {
                    if (tipo == "P")
                    {
                        model_campo.IdAgen = idAgen;
                    }
                    else if (tipo == "C")
                    {
                        model_campo.IdAgenC = idAgen;
                    }
                    else if (tipo == "I")
                    {
                        model_campo.IdAgenI = idAgen;
                    }

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  
                    return Ok(model);
                }
                return BadRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: La condición del `Linq` está recuperando 11 registros pero el `SingleOrDefault()` sólo espera 1 registro. Verifica si la condición  del `where` es la correcta o te falta alguna condición que efectivamente asegure recupere 1 registro. Ahora si quieres recuperar sólo el primero utiliza `FirstOrDefault`. El problema te da en el `SaveChangesAsync` porque es en ese momento que la consulta se realiza.

Comment: Huntzberger, seria bueno que dijeres si las respuestas te fueron utiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses el **método** **SingleOrDefault**, usa el **método** **FirstOrDefault**.

**SingleOrDefault** devuelve el único elemento que hay en una colección, es decir esta colección solamente tendrá uno o ningún elemento. Si esta colección tuviese más de un elemento ocurre un error.

**FirstOrDefault** devuelve el primer elemento de una colección sin importar si esta tiene uno o muchos elementos.

En ambos casos se devuelve **null** si la colección está vacía.